# Joining tables from multiple databases using

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'd like to group together MariaDB tables with similar functionality into different databases. What is the preferred way of executing JOIN operation using PHP PDO on tables from multiple databases? Is there any performance penalty for doing that? Usually I only connect to 1 database at the time.

Is there some other way to organize mariadb tables? I am using Sequel Pro, and it is hard to work with when the number of tables increases to 50 or more with no visible separation between them.

Comment: Are the new databases on the same server?

Comment: yes, on the same

Comment: then you can do a query with database1.table1 inner join databasse2,table2 and never forget to add teh databases

Comment: But there is no need for such a thing a new table is enough and you will not get any better performance by splitting it into 2 databases.

Comment: Thanks. So no performance penalties and no performance increase. Also, I am aware of the sql sytax, but have no idea how to do it using PDO. When using pdo, you first create a connection to a database. Pressumably just one. How do you make a join if the connection is made to just one database?

Comment: yes but is only because the users had to do a use database1 so that querys work, because they forget to put in front the databases name. When you clarify the databases the initial use one doesn't matter

Comment: Joining tables has nothing to do with PHP or PDO

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest you to be careful with this especially If you wan't to achieve performance from your code. Carefully read documentation about `JOIN` what it does when you combining two tables, also suggesting you to read about indexing and unqiue keys in MariaDB. Good Luck :)